# C socket programming buffer contains rolling message

Tags: c, server, client

I have a client server chat application I am working on. I am having issues with the buffer. I am not sure how to add a null-byte or where to add this so that the buffer does not overflow when the client and server are communicating. Not sure what the issue is but I know it has something to do with the buffer. This is a challenging architecture to debug. Just to reiterate the problem is that the message from the client's previous chat is still in the buffer and bleeds out on the server side after a few chats.

Bellow is the server side program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

int main(){
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port=htons(8080);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    
    if(bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(server_address))==-1){
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     
    if(listen(server_socket,10)==-1){
        perror("Error listening for connection");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int client_socket = accept(server_socket,NULL,NULL);

    if(client_socket==-1){
        perror("Error accepting connection");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[1024];

    while(1){
        //size of buffer recieved
        //receive message from the client
        recv(client_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
        printf("Client: %s\n",buffer);
       

        //send message to client
        printf("Server: ");
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
        send(client_socket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
        
    }

    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;

}
```

Below is the client program

```
// Client
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
    int client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8080);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(server_address.sin_addr));

    if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
        perror("Error connecting to server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[1024];

    while (1) {
        // Send message to server
        printf("Client: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        send(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

        // Receive message from server
        recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);
       
    }

    close(client_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried adding a null-byte in the buffer somewhere in the code before the recv function.

Comment: You need to save the the value that `recv` returns. Both for checking for errors, connection closed, and *the size of the data received*.

Comment: You should really check what `fgets` and `send` returns as well.

Comment: And lastly note that TCP is a streaming protocol, with no message boundaries or message separators. It's a just a stream of bytes. That means you might not be able to receive everything from a `send` call with just a single `recv` call. You might need multiple `recv` call. Or you can get data from multiple `send` calls in a single call to `recv`.

Comment: Might be time to get a [good reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_Network_Programming) on how to do this properly. There's a lot of easy mistakes to make.

Answer (score 0):

You try to send a message of size len(buffer) (= 13 for "hello world" for exemple) and recv a message of size sizeof(buffer) = 1024 (because of buffer[1024] so your server try to recv a some byte that doesn't exist in the socket, it's like read str[50] when you have only malloc a size of 10.

To avoid that I suggest you to send 2 informations : first of all send the size of the message as a size_t then send the message.
The recever will recv the size_t then read the socket again with this size.

Take exemple of this, there is some function I use :

```
int CFStream_host(int port)
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(port),
        .sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY,
    };

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(fd, 100) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int CFStream_connect(const char *host, int port)
{
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(port),
        .sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host),
    };

    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int CFStream_send(int fd, const char *request, size_t len)
{
    if (write(fd, &len, sizeof(len)) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        return -1;
    }

    if (write(fd, request, len) == -1) {
        perror("write");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

char *CFStream_recv(int fd)
{
    size_t len;
    if (read(fd, &len, sizeof(len)) <= 0) {
        perror("read");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *buf = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!buf) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (read(fd, buf, len) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return NULL;
    }

    buf[len] = '\0';

    return buf;
}

int CFStream_close(int fd)
{
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```